# Generate a random list based on limited items with spock-genesis

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I use [spock-genesis](https://bijnagte.github.io/spock-genesis/) and would like to have an infinite lists generator parametrized with a list of values. A generated item should be a list that contains at most the list of parametrized values in random order.

Some invariants are:

```
def 'list generator'() {
    expect:
    xs.size() <= 3
    xs.findAll({x -> x == 1}).size() <= 1
    xs.findAll({x -> x == 2}).size() <= 1
    xs.findAll({x -> x == 3}).size() <= 1

    where:
    xs << listGen([1, 2, 3])
}
```

I'm about to write own Generator implementation but there is chance I overthink something and it's possible to compose such generator with already existing spock-genesis units.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List listGen(List list) {
    list.subsequences()
            .collect { it.permutations() }
            .inject([[]]) { result, subseq -> result + subseq }
}
```

The result of `listGen([1, 2, 3])` will be:

```
[[], [1], [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1], [2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [3, 1]]
```

Your test passes with this implementation.

**UPD:**
As per the OP clarifications below in the comments, they expect the permutations to be random, so here is the line of code that will do that using [spock-genesis any](https://bijnagte.github.io/spock-genesis/#_any):

```
where:
xs << Gen.any(listGen([1, 2, 3])).take(42).collect() // I assume 42 here should be random as well then
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, your suggestion could be a good base to implement a generator. Empty  list should be added to the result as well. But my question is more about using existing spock-genesis generators and posibility to combine them in order to obtain the results. In the end I need a generator that gives me fairly random lists.

Comment: @TsimonDorakh so you can easily replace the `[1, 2, 3]` with a random list then. It doesn't matter how you generate that initial random list, whether using spock-genesis or some other option. No problem with adding an empty list to the result either.

Comment: [1,2,3] is not going to be random. I expect its permutation be random per each iteration.

Comment: @TsimonDorakh I've updated the answer to support the requirement of the permutations being random + the empty list is also there now (see updated `inject([[]])`)

Comment: looks great, thanks! No need to have ".take(42).collect()" as "xs << Gen.any(listGen([1, 2, 3]))" infinitely generates the lists with random permutations.

Comment: @TsimonDorakh I've purposefully limited the generator for the test spec. Otherwise, your test is not going to finish.

Comment: Trying to figure out the time complexity of the method. At first glance it's >O(n!). But without knowing underlying implementations complexity it's hard to say...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, is just a list of  every possible permutation of the list `[1,2,3]`? If so then this should be enough.

```
[1, 2, 3].permutations()
```

Comment: permutations do not give results as [], [1], [1,2], etc

Answer (score 0):

With @Dmitry Khamitov help I've come up with spock-genesis generator

```
package spock.genesis.generators.composites

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import spock.genesis.generators.Generator
import spock.genesis.generators.UnmodifiableIterator
import spock.genesis.generators.values.RandomElementGenerator

/** A lazy infinite {@code Generator} that returns a random subset of elements from a source Collection
 * @warning O(n!) time complexity. Starts being too expensive with lists 10+ elements
 * @param < E >     the generated type
 */
@CompileStatic
class ListSubsetGenerator<E> extends Generator<List<E>> {
    final RandomElementGenerator<List<E>> valueSource

    ListSubsetGenerator(Collection<E> source) {
        this.valueSource = new RandomElementGenerator<>(getListsSource(source))
    }

    private List<List<E>> getListsSource(Collection<E> source) {
        source.toList().subsequences()
            .collect { it.permutations() }
            .inject([[]]) { result, subseq ->
                result.addAll(subseq)
                result
            } as List<List<E>>
    }

    @Override
    UnmodifiableIterator<List<E>> iterator() {
        new UnmodifiableIterator<List<E>>() {
            private final Iterator<List<E>> source = valueSource.iterator()

            @Override
            boolean hasNext() {
                source.hasNext()
            }

            @Override
            List<E> next() {
                source.next()
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    Generator<List<E>> seed(Long seed) {
        super.seed(seed)
        valueSource.seed(seed)
        this
    }
}
```

Here are some tests:

```
class ListSubsetGeneratorTest extends Specification {
    @Iterations(100)
    def 'test invariants'() {
        expect:
        xs.size() <= 3
        xs.findAll({x -> x == 1}).size() <= 1
        xs.findAll({x -> x == 2}).size() <= 1
        xs.findAll({x -> x == 3}).size() <= 1
        xs.every { [1, 2, 3].contains(it) }

        where:
        xs << new ListSubsetGenerator([1, 2, 3])
    }

    def 'setting seed produces the same sequences for different generators'() {
        given:
        def elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        def xs = new ListSubsetGenerator(elements).seed(seed).take(100).realized
        def ys = new ListSubsetGenerator(elements).seed(seed).take(100).realized

        expect:
        xs == ys

        where:
        seed << [Long.MIN_VALUE, 100, Long.MAX_VALUE]
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question, why do you want an infinite List? You'll get repeated elements, at least for the example of `[1,2,3]` the total size is only 16, so taking 100 is just wasting compute resources. Do you want to combine it with other generators?

Comment: [1,2,3] is just a simple example of source data. It could be any list with any count of values. From infinite generator I can always make a finite one, but not vice versa. And yes, I would like to combine the generator with others like Type, etc.